# What are some solutions for repetitive sound playback in C# using System.Media library?

Tags: c#, .net, media, naudio, audio-player

I'm using the C# System.Media library to create a keyboard piano, but I'm encountering a problem.
When I play the sound, it keeps repeating itself.
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer media = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    media.Play(C.wav);
}
```

I have also tried writing my own sounds using a binary writer, but the playback is not working correctly.
And I write own sounds with binary writer etc. but it's not playing.

Do you have any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `public void playMethod(string a)
        {
            media.SoundLocation = a;
            playCoutner = 0;
            while(!isPlay&&playCoutner==0){
                media.Play();
                isPlay = true;
            }
            playCoutner = 1;
        }
if(note == "c")
{
media.Play(c1);
}
else{
 media.Stop();
  isPlay = false;
 playCoutner = 1;
}`

I found like solution like this I kept playCounter int for future modification maybe I will add chrods or something, any advice guys?

Comment: Don't use comments to add generally useful information to your posts: use the `Edit` below the tag list.